# How to permute(shuffle) dynamic/linked list in C

Tags: c, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I use this data structure to store a graph:

```
struct Vertex
{
    struct Line *a;
    struct Line *b;
    int X;
    int Y;
    struct Vertex *next;
    struct Edge *edges;
    int edgeCount;
};
struct Edge
{
   struct Vertex *dst;
   struct Vertex *src;
   struct Edge *next;
   float weight;
   bool included;
   bool visited;
};
```

I generate a linked list of vertices(the list is my graph) in a loop:

```
struct Edge *edge= malloc(sizeof(struct Edge));
////here I add edge's data
if(graph->edges == NULL)
{
    graph->edges = edge;
}
else
{
    edge->next = graph->edges;
}
```

And now I need to permute resulting array. It is simple with common array of integers:

```
void swap(int a, int b)
{
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}

void permutation(int* randomArray, int numIndex)
{
  for (i = 0; i < numIndex; i++)
  {
    int randomOffset = rand() % (numIndex - i);
    swap(randomArray[i], randomArray[i+randomOffset]);
  }
}
```

But how to do the same with linked list?

Comment: You can't.  You would have to run through and change all of the pointers around and then pass through it.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of `struct Edge *` that contains all edges, built when the linked list is created, permute that array, rebuild the linked list.

The variables

```
struct Edge *pedges[MAXEDGES]; // or allocate dynamically (see below)
int nedges = 0;
```

then when list is created

```
struct Edge *edge= malloc(sizeof(struct Edge)); // your code
pedges[nedges++] = edge;
```

permutations are done the same way

```
void permuteEdges(struct Edge *pe, int ne) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0 ; i < ne ; i++) {
      int randomOffset = rand() % (ne - i);
      swap(pe[i], pe[i+randomOffset]);
   }
}
```

finally, rebuild the linked list

```
for (i = 0 ; i < ne ; i++) {
   if ( ! i) {
      graph->edges = pe[i];
   }
   else {
      pe[i-1]->next = pe[i];
   }
}
```

ensure the last item next property points to NULL

```
pe[ne-1]->next = NULL;
```

---

Note that you could allocate `pedges` dynamically (to be freed after use).  For instance if you use the array for a single shuffle, there is no need to keep that amount of memory in the heap.

Dynamic allocation

```
struct Edge *pedges = malloc(MAXEDGES * sizeof(*pedges));

...use it...

free(pedges);
```

Comment: Just a simple point of clarification - what is the intent of dynamically allocating "*if you need to do this only once...*"? Wouldn't it make more sense to dynamically allocate "*if you need to do this **more than** once...*". If the array of pointers will fit on the stack, wouldn't it make more sense to take advantage of the efficiencies of static allocation and code simplicity until dynamic allocation was needed?

Comment: That's OK, it was just a little unclear what the intent was. Thanks.